# Changing a value of an index in a buffer array

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer, buffer, requestly

so I am using requestly to modify the http responses

```
function modifyResponse(args) {
  const {method, url, response, responseType, requestHeaders, requestData, responseJSON} = args;
  console.log(response)
  return response;
}
```

so this function returns response, response is the actual response coming from the server, I can change it with the function, the problem is this: when I console.log the response I get this

```
ArrayBuffer(53)
byteLength: 53
[[Prototype]]: ArrayBuffer
[[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(53)
[[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(53)
[[ArrayBufferByteLength]]: 53
[[ArrayBufferData]]: 629
```

https://ibb.co/zQVbvLq

I tried reading through the array (image above), and found out that it's all in ascii, that is not the problem,I want to do something like this

```
Int8Array[0] = 10
```

the problem is that I don't have the knowledge to do it, I don't know how to access Int8Array through the modifyResponse function.

I have to change the function to something like this :

```
function modifyResponse(args) {
  const {method, url, response, responseType, requestHeaders, requestData, responseJSON} = args;
  //console.log(response)
response[Int8Array[0]] = 10
  return response;
}
```

I basically have to access response then access Int8Array and then change the element at index 0, but it does not work :/
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The `[[Int8Array]]` is an internal property - you cannot simply access it as you would with any other property.

If you want to edit the `ArrayBuffer` as an `Int8Array` you need to construct it like so:

```js
const array = new Int8Array(response);
array[0] = 10;
return response;
```